# Timestamp conversion in postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

**Problem**

How to convert 2022-06-14T12:47:00.560Z to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss (2022-06-14 12:47:00)

**what I have tried is**

```
select to_timestamp(to_char('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
select to_timestamp('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

**What issues I am getting**

> Error while connecting to PostgreSQL Execution failed on sql 'select
> to_timestamp(to_char('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD
> HH24:MI:SS'))': TEIID30068 The function
> 'to_char('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')' is an
> unknown form.  Check that the function name and number of arguments is
> correct.

> Error while connecting to PostgreSQL Execution failed on sql 'select
> to_timestamp('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')':
> TEIID30068 The function 'to_timestamp('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z',
> 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')' is an unknown form.  Check that the function
> name and number of arguments is correct.

Please help me in converting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
select to_timestamp('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntiwq62xZpVt5CSnVytLsf/0).

**EDIT**

I though you needed to parse the timestamp only. Now I realize you want to format it back to a string. You can add `to_char()` to format it as needed.

For example:

```
select
  to_char(
    to_timestamp('2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
  );
```

See [updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntiwq62xZpVt5CSnVytLsf/1).

Comment: Hi Impaler, 
I could see still 'T' is present in the result. Can you please check. 
The need is to get 2022-06-14 13:04:00

Comment: HI all, the above 2 solutions are fine DB fiddle. When I implement in python code it is always giving an issue (unknown form as mentioned in the description).

Answer (score 3):

you can use built in timestamo conversion

> ```
> SELECT timestamp '2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z'
> ```
>
> ```
> | timestamp              |
> | :--------------------- |
> | 2022-06-14 13:04:00.61 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT '2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z'::timestamp
> ```
>
> ```
> | timestamp              |
> | :--------------------- |
> | 2022-06-14 13:04:00.61 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=53da276b54408194c48406b210a993cc)*

You can use date_trunc

> ```
> SELECT date_trunc('second',timestamp '2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z')
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_trunc          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-06-14 13:04:00 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT date_trunc('second','2022-06-14T13:04:00.610Z'::timestamp)
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_trunc          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-06-14 13:04:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=91d8fa09d984c598ac7190bc07a44952)*

Comment: Hi nbk, what to do if I dont need to have .61 in the result ? The requirement is to get 2022-06-14 13:04:00

Comment: you need to use date_trunc  timestamp(0)  would round the result